# swift 2.0 UIWebview displays white page only

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I write this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL (string: "http://google.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);

    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

run the code, iPhone simulator display white page only but no warning error

and I change the code to:

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://apple.com");
```

just change google to apple, then it works - simulator displayed apple site

So I put the other site `url` but it's same like first one, only it displays `apple.com`

I don't know what is wrong about this code please help me! thank you :)

Comment: webView is already added in View... so why u add it again in self.view... because you are already connect this to ibOutlet...it means it is already in view... so no need of addSubView

Answer (score 2):

You should get the error:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

Find Info as the image below shows and do the steps:

```
1.On the last line add the +
2.Enter the name of the group: App Transport Security
3.Right click on the group and select Add Row
4.Enter Allow Arbitrary Loads
5.Set the value on the right to YES
```

[image]

**no need this line if you have connect it from storyboard**

```
self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

Answer (score 1):

App Transport Security has prevented your web view from loading the page over `http`. You can either disable it, per William Hu's answer, or switch over to using `https` links (which is the recommended option).